# How to resolve bibtex references

Tags: bibtex

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.unf.edu/~wkloster/latex/bib.html).

qhe.bib file:

```
@STRING(PRL="Phys. Rev. Lett.")
@STRING(RMP="Rev. Mod. Phys.")

@ARTICLE{klitzing:qhe,
   AUTHOR="K. von Klitzing and G. Dorda and M. Pepper",
   TITLE="New method for high accuracy determination of fine structure
            constant based on quantised hall resistance",
   JOURNAL=PRL,
   VOLUME=45,
   PAGES=494,
   YEAR=1980
}

@ARTICLE{klitzing:nobel,
   AUTHOR="Klaus von Klitzing",
   TITLE="The Quantised Hall Effect",
   JOURNAL=RMP,
   VOLUME=58,
   PAGES=519,
   YEAR=1986
}
```

example.tex:

```
\documentstyle{article}
\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{prsty} % Choose Phys. Rev. style for bibliography

\section{Introduction}
The discovery of the Quantised Hall Effect was made by
Klitzing~\cite{klitzing:qhe} for which he was awarded the 1985 Nobel
prize for physics~\cite{klitzing:nobel}.

\bibliography{qhe}        % qhe.bib is the name of our database

\end{document}
```

commands used:

```
latex example
bibtex example
latex example
latex example
```

errors from latex:

> LaTeX Warning: Citation `klitzing:qhe' on page 1 undefined on input
>   line 8.
>
> LaTeX Warning: Citation `klitzing:nobel' on page 1 undefined on input
>   line 9.

errors from bibtex:

> I couldn't open style file prsty.bst
>   I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file example.aux

I tried changing bibliographystyle to bibstyle, but got the same error.

Comment: You should be getting an error message that the `prsty` bibliography style couldn't be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, bibtex was unable to recognize the style. In my BibTeX Version 0.99d, the following modifications worked:

```
\documentclass{article}              % modified to class to accommodate the style

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}         % use package for style

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}         % style changed
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to download `prsty.bst`. 
Try locally if you need some fast solution and install it correctly if you have time :)